# Type A problem was encountered using TagExtraInfo class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI for 'c:forEach;

Tags: java, jsp

I wandered through out the stackoverflow but could not find the correct solution that resolves my issue.

```
Type A problem was encountered using TagExtraInfo class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI for 'c:forEach'
```

This error is being displayed whenever I am using

> <c:forEach></c:forEach>

and

> <c:import></c:import>

Other tags are showing no warning.

I am using Eclipse IDE and Tomcat Server version 10.0

Please tell me how can I resolve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My solution was changing settings in Preferences->Web->JSP Files->Validation "Other problems with TagExtraInfo class: ignore"

Answer (score 1):

I have updated Eclipse IDE to the newer version and there is no such error now.